# How to optimise function logic to avoid duplication - python

Tags: python, if-statement, logic

I have some code below, for a given name that matches pattern with 2 lower case letters (such as 'aa'), the valid name can be `V-aa` or `X-aa`

```
def verify_helper(valid_name):
    do something
    return true #meaning the name starts either V or X is valid


def example(name): 
     
    if re.match("^[a-z]{2}$", name)
        valid_name_1 = f"V-{name}"
        valid_name_2 = f"X-{name}"  
    
    verify_helper(valid_name_1)
    verify_helper(valid_name_2)
```

My question is: can I do something like:

```
def example(name): 
     
    if re.match("^[a-z]{2}$", name)
        valid_name_1 = f"V-{name}"
        valid_name_2 = f"X-{name}"  
    
    if valid_name matches either 'V-' or 'X-'
    call the first function
```

Comment: You never assigned `valid_name`. That's just a parameter variable in the first function, which you haven't called yet. I'm not sure what you mean in your question.

Comment: If the first function checks whether the name begins with `V-` or `X-`, what's the point of checking that before calling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, I assume that `verify_helper()` is computationally expensive regardless of `names` being `valid`.

Now you want to optimize the code, by having `verify_helper()` only execute for `valid names`.

If that's the case, you could have the condition inside `verify_helper()`, like this.

```
def verify_helper(name):
    if re.match("^[XV]-[a-z]{2}", name): # checks for valid names like X-aa, X-aa11, V-bb etc.
        # do something only for valid names
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Hi the issue is that for a given name, it must have a certain pattern of ‘^[a-z]{2}$’, so anything like ‘X-aa11’ or ‘V-aa11’ are valid, things like ‘X-a’, ‘V-a’ are not valid

Comment: Please see my comment above :) @Reuben

Comment: `X-aa11` does not conform to `^[a-z]{2}$` in your comment. I think what you're looking for is `^[XV]-[a-z]{2}`